# Why is failbit() set?

Tags: c++, istream

Create a file and fill it up with zeroes:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/zeroes count=1
```

Write this little program to extract the first unsigned integer it encounters in the file.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream reader( "/tmp/zeroes", std::ios_base::binary );
    uint32_t number;
    reader >> number;

    assert( !reader.fail() );
}
```

Why is the assert triggered?

Comment: Even if you set the stream mode to binary, `>>` to an integer type is a formatted input function (uses `num_get` which expects a text representation).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `/dev/zero` delivers binary zeros, not the character
`'0'`, and `>>` does (or tries to do) a conversion from text.